# How do I sort an array of strings, by the ascending occurence of a 'word' in the string? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have the following strings in an array:

```
let strings = ['cat bone Dog', 'Dogcat bone', 'cat Dog bone'];
.
.
.
.
return sortedString = ['Dogcat bone', 'cat Dog bone', 'cat bone Dog'];
```

I'm thinking of using `localeCompare` but I don't know how to specify to sort by a certain set of characters, in this case, I want to sort by the 'Dog'.

I can still have the word 'Dog' be attached to other words without spaces, like 'Dogcat bone'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string by spaces, and return the difference of the `indexOf` the word you're looking for in the array:

```js
let strings = ['cat bone Dog', 'Dog cat bone', 'cat Dog bone'];
const getDogPos = string => string.split(' ').indexOf('Dog');

strings.sort((a, b) => getDogPos(a) - getDogPos(b));
console.log(strings);
```

If you want to sort by the position of the *substring* in the string, rather than the position of the *word*, then just use `indexOf` without splitting first:

```js
let strings = ['cat bone Dog', 'Dogcat bone', 'cat Dog bone'];
const getDogPos = string => string.indexOf('Dog');

strings.sort((a, b) => getDogPos(a) - getDogPos(b));
console.log(strings);
```

Comment: What if there was a string with 'Dogcat bone'? How do I go about then? I still want the Dog to be first.

Comment: If you're looking for the index of the substring, rather than the index of the word, then just use `indexOf` without splitting first

Comment: I just thought of that. Thanks anyway. Let me try it.

Comment: I'm assuming that the `=>` is an arrow function? Why do you subtract `getDogPos(a) - getDogPos(b)`? Thanks

Comment: You want to sort the strings by the *differences* in the index of the word. Eg, index 1 comes before index 2, index 2 comes before index 3, index 3 comes *after* index 1 - that's the logic that subtracting implements, and that [`.sort` recognizes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)